# Servidor SUSE 11.3 se apaga

Tags: linux

Tengo un servidor que se ha estado apagando constantemente, sospecho que es algo de la funete de poder, este es el output de dmesg.

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:  
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009d000 (usable)  
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 000000000009d000 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)  
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)  
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bddac000 (usable)  
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000bddac000 - 00000000bddde000 (ACPI data)  
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000bddde000 - 00000000d0000000 (reserved)  
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fec00000 - 00000000fee10000 (reserved)  
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000ff800000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)  
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000100000000 - 000000303ffff000 (usable)  
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active  
[    0.000000] DMI 2.8 present.  
[    0.000000] DMI: HP ProLiant BL460c Gen8, BIOS I31 06/01/2015  
[    0.000000] e820 update range: 0000000000000000 - 0000000000010000 (usable) ==> (reserved)  
[    0.000000] e820 remove range: 00000000000a0000 - 0000000000100000 (usable)  
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found  
[    0.000000] last_pfn = 0x303ffff max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000  
[    0.000000] MTRR default type: write-back  
[    0.000000] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:  
[    0.000000]   00000-9FFFF write-back  
[    0.000000]   A0000-BFFFF uncachable  
[    0.000000]   C0000-FFFFF write-protect  
[    0.000000] MTRR variable ranges enabled:  
[    0.000000]   0 base 0000C0000000 mask 3FFFC0000000 uncachable  
[    0.000000]   1 disabled  
[    0.000000]   2 disabled  
[    0.000000]   3 disabled  
[    0.000000]   4 disabled  
[    0.000000]   5 disabled  
[    0.000000]   6 disabled  
[    0.000000]   7 disabled  
[    0.000000]   8 disabled  
[    0.000000]   9 disabled  
[    0.000000] x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106  
[    0.000000] last_pfn = 0xbddac max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000  
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [ffff8800000f4f80] f4f80  
[    0.000000] initial memory mapped : 0 - 20000000  
[    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [ffff880000098000] 98000 size 20480  
[    0.000000] Using GB pages for direct mapping  
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-00000000bddac000  
[    0.000000]  0000000000 - 0080000000 page 1G  
[    0.000000]  0080000000 - 00bdc00000 page 2M  
[    0.000000]  00bdc00000 - 00bddac000 page 4k  
[    0.000000] kernel direct mapping tables up to 0xbddabfff @ [mem 0x1fffd000-0x1fffffff]  
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: 0000000100000000-000000303ffff000  
[    0.000000]  0100000000 - 3000000000 page 1G  
[    0.000000]  3000000000 - 303fe00000 page 2M  
[    0.000000]  303fe00000 - 303ffff000 page 4k  
[    0.000000] kernel direct mapping tables up to 0x303fffefff @ [mem 0xbdda9000-0xbddabfff]  
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: 377e5000 - 37ff0000  
[    0.000000] Reserving 128MB of memory at 752MB for crashkernel (System RAM: 197631MB)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 00000000000f4f00 00024 (v02 HP    )  
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 00000000bddaed00 000EC (v01 HP     ProLiant 00000002   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 00000000bddaee40 000F4 (v03 HP     ProLiant 00000002   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI Warning: Invalid length for Pm1aControlBlock: 32, using default 16 (20110413/tbfadt-611)  
[    0.000000] ACPI Warning: Invalid length for Pm2ControlBlock: 32, using default 8 (20110413/tbfadt-611)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 00000000bddaef40 026DC (v01 HP         DSDT 00000001 INTL 20030228)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 00000000bddac140 00040  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SPCR 00000000bddac180 00050 (v01 HP     SPCRRBSU 00000001   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 00000000bddac200 0003C (v01 HP     ProLiant 00000001      00000000)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 00000000bddac240 00038 (v01 HP     ProLiant 00000002   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: FFFF 00000000bddac280 00064 (v02 HP     ProLiant 00000002   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SPMI 00000000bddac300 00040 (v05 HP     ProLiant 00000001   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: ERST 00000000bddac340 00230 (v01 HP     ProLiant 00000001   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 00000000bddac580 0026A (v01 HP     ProLiant 00000002      00000000)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SRAT 00000000bddac800 00750 (v01 HP     Proliant 00000001   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: FFFF 00000000bddacf80 00176 (v01 HP     ProLiant 00000001   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: BERT 00000000bddad100 00030 (v01 HP     ProLiant 00000001   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: HEST 00000000bddad140 000BC (v01 HP     ProLiant 00000001   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: DMAR 00000000bddad200 0060C (v01 HP     ProLiant 00000001   Ò? 0000162E)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: FFFF 00000000bddaec40 00030 (v01 HP     ProLiant 00000001      00000000)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: PCCT 00000000bddaec80 0006E (v01 HP     Proliant 00000001   PH 0000504D)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bddb1640 007EA (v01     HP DEV_PCI1 00000001 INTL 20120503)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bddb1e40 00103 (v03     HP  CRSPCI0 00000002   HP 00000001)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bddb1f80 00098 (v03     HP  CRSPCI1 00000002   HP 00000001)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bddb2040 00413 (v03     HP embedded 00000002 INTL 20030228)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bddb2480 0038A (v02     HP   riser0 00000002 INTL 20030228)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bddb2840 00263 (v03     HP embedde2 00000002 INTL 20030228)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bddb2ac0 00BB9 (v01     HP      pcc 00000001 INTL 20120503)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bddb3680 00377 (v01     HP     pmab 00000001 INTL 20120503)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bddb3a00 05524 (v01     HP     pcc2 00000001 INTL 20120503)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 00000000bddb8f40 04E84 (v01 INTEL  PPM RCM  00000001 INTL 20061109)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x00 -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x01 -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x02 -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x03 -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x04 -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x05 -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x06 -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x07 -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x08 -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x09 -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x0a -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x0b -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x0c -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x0d -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x0e -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x0f -> Node 0  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x20 -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x21 -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x22 -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x23 -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x24 -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x25 -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x26 -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x27 -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x28 -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x29 -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x2a -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x2b -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x2c -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x2d -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x2e -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 0x2f -> Node 1  
[    0.000000] SRAT: Node 0 PXM 0 0-1840000000  
[    0.000000] SRAT: Node 1 PXM 1 1840000000-3040000000  
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 0000000000000000-0000001840000000  
[    0.000000]   NODE_DATA [000000183ffd9000 - 000000183fffffff]  
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 1 0000001840000000-000000303ffff000  
[    0.000000]   NODE_DATA [000000303ffd8080 - 000000303ffff07f]  
[    0.000000]  [ffffea0000000000-ffffea0054dfffff] PMD -> [ffff8817dfe00000-ffff881833dfffff] on node 0  
[    0.000000]  [ffffea0054e00000-ffffea00a8dfffff] PMD -> [ffff882fdf600000-ffff8830335fffff] on node 1  
[    0.000000] Zone PFN ranges:  
[    0.000000]   DMA      0x00000010 -> 0x00001000  
[    0.000000]   DMA32    0x00001000 -> 0x00100000  
[    0.000000]   Normal   0x00100000 -> 0x0303ffff  
[    0.000000] Movable zone start PFN for each node  
[    0.000000] early_node_map[4] active PFN ranges  
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00000010 -> 0x0000009d  
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00000100 -> 0x000bddac  
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00100000 -> 0x01840000  
[    0.000000]     1: 0x01840000 -> 0x0303ffff  
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 25156921  
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 56 pages used for memmap  
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 5 pages reserved  
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 3920 pages, LIFO batch:0  
[    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 14280 pages used for memmap  
[    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 759268 pages, LIFO batch:31  
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 333312 pages used for memmap  
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 24046080 pages, LIFO batch:31  
[    0.000000] On node 1 totalpages: 25165823  
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 344064 pages used for memmap  
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 24821759 pages, LIFO batch:31  
[    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x908  
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x02] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x04] lapic_id[0x04] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x06] lapic_id[0x06] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x08] lapic_id[0x08] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0a] lapic_id[0x0a] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0c] lapic_id[0x0c] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0e] lapic_id[0x0e] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x20] lapic_id[0x20] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x22] lapic_id[0x22] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x24] lapic_id[0x24] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x26] lapic_id[0x26] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x28] lapic_id[0x28] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x2a] lapic_id[0x2a] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x2c] lapic_id[0x2c] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x2e] lapic_id[0x2e] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x01] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x03] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x05] lapic_id[0x05] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x07] lapic_id[0x07] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x09] lapic_id[0x09] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0b] lapic_id[0x0b] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0d] lapic_id[0x0d] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x0f] lapic_id[0x0f] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x21] lapic_id[0x21] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x23] lapic_id[0x23] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x25] lapic_id[0x25] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x27] lapic_id[0x27] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x29] lapic_id[0x29] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x2b] lapic_id[0x2b] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x2d] lapic_id[0x2d] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x2f] lapic_id[0x2f] enabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] dfl dfl lint[0x1])  
[    0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x08] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])  
[    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 8, version 32, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23  
[    0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x00] address[0xfec10000] gsi_base[24])  
[    0.000000] IOAPIC[1]: apic_id 0, version 32, address 0xfec10000, GSI 24-47  
[    0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x0a] address[0xfec40000] gsi_base[48])  
[    0.000000] IOAPIC[2]: apic_id 10, version 32, address 0xfec40000, GSI 48-71  
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 high edge)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)  
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.  
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ2 used by override.  
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.  
[    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information  
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000  
[    0.000000] SMP: Allowing 64 CPUs, 32 hotplug CPUs  
[    0.000000] nr_irqs_gsi: 88  
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009d000 - 00000000000a0000  
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000f0000  
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000  
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000bddac000 - 00000000bddde000  
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000bddde000 - 00000000d0000000  
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000d0000000 - 00000000fec00000  
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fec00000 - 00000000fee10000  
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fee10000 - 00000000ff800000  
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000ff800000 - 0000000100000000  
[    0.000000] Allocating PCI resources starting at d0000000 (gap: d0000000:2ec00000)  
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware  
[    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:4096 nr_cpumask_bits:64 nr_cpu_ids:64 nr_node_ids:2  
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 26 pages/cpu @ffff88183fa00000 s75264 r8192 d23040 u131072  
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s75264 r8192 d23040 u131072 alloc=1*2097152  
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23   
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 62   
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [1] 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31   
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [1] 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49 51 53 55 57 59 61 63   
[    0.000000] Built 2 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 49631027  
[    0.000000] Policy zone: Normal  
id/scsi-3600508b1001c762f83babda266e088bf-part1 splash=silent crashkernel=256M-:128M vga=normal  
[    0.000000] bootsplash: silent mode.  
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)  
[    0.000000] xsave/xrstor: enabled xstate_bv 0x7, cntxt size 0x340  
[    0.000000] Checking aperture...  
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found  
[    0.000000] Queued invalidation will be enabled to support x2apic and Intr-remapping.  
1360k init)  
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.  
[    0.000000]  RCU dyntick-idle grace-period acceleration is enabled.  
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:262400 nr_irqs:2008 16  
[    0.000000] Console: colour VGA+ 80x25  
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled  
[    0.000000] allocated 1610612736 bytes of page_cgroup  
[    0.000000] please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups  
[    0.000000] hpet clockevent registered  
[    0.000000] Fast TSC calibration using PIT  
[    0.004000] Detected 2700.017 MHz processor.  
[    0.000020] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 5400.03 BogoMIPS (lpj=10800068)  
[    0.000260] pid_max: default: 65536 minimum: 512  
[    0.000565] kdb version 4.4 by Keith Owens, Scott Lurndal. Copyright SGI, All Rights Reserved  
[    0.001478] Security Framework initialized  
[    0.001610] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized  
[    0.014206] Dentry cache hash table entries: 33554432 (order: 16, 268435456 bytes)  
[    0.058305] Inode-cache hash table entries: 16777216 (order: 15, 134217728 bytes)  
[    0.077161] Mount-cache hash table entries: 256  
[    0.077471] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct  
[    0.077594] Initializing cgroup subsys memory  
[    0.077741] Initializing cgroup subsys devices  
[    0.077861] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer  
[    0.077978] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls  
[    0.078094] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio  
[    0.078216] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event  
[    0.078395] CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0  
[    0.078514] CPU: Processor Core ID: 0  
[    0.078634] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Is set to 'performance'  
[    0.078635] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: View and update with cpupower-set(8)  
[    0.078882] mce: CPU supports 20 MCE banks  
[    0.079020] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)  
[    0.079140] using mwait in idle threads.  
[    0.079993] ACPI: Core revision 20110413  
[    0.084682] DMAR: Host address width 46  
[    0.084809] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fbefe000 flags: 0x0  
[    0.084934] IOMMU 0: reg_base_addr fbefe000 ver 1:0 cap d2078c106f0462 ecap f020fe  
[    0.085118] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000f4ffe000 flags: 0x1  
[    0.085242] IOMMU 1: reg_base_addr f4ffe000 ver 1:0 cap d2078c106f0462 ecap f020fe  
[    0.085422] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000bdffd000 end: 0x000000bdffffff  
[    0.085541] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000bdff6000 end: 0x000000bdffcfff  
[    0.085661] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000bdf83000 end: 0x000000bdf84fff  
[    0.085779] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000bdf7f000 end: 0x000000bdf82fff  
[    0.085900] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000bdf6f000 end: 0x000000bdf7efff  
[    0.086020] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000bdf6e000 end: 0x000000bdf6efff  
[    0.086140] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000000f4000 end: 0x000000000f4fff  
[    0.086259] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000000e8000 end: 0x000000000e8fff  
[    0.086378] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000bddde000 end: 0x000000bdddefff  
[    0.086498] DMAR: ATSR flags: 0x0  
[    0.086731] IOAPIC id 10 under DRHD base  0xfbefe000 IOMMU 0  
[    0.086851] IOAPIC id 8 under DRHD base  0xf4ffe000 IOMMU 1  
[    0.086970] IOAPIC id 0 under DRHD base  0xf4ffe000 IOMMU 1  
[    0.087088] HPET id 0 under DRHD base 0xf4ffe000  
[    0.087206] BIOS requests to not use x2apic  
[    0.087206] Use 'intremap=no_x2apic_optout' to override BIOS request  
[    0.087830] Enabled IRQ remapping in xapic mode  
[    0.087947] x2apic not enabled, IRQ remapping is in xapic mode  
[    0.088066] Switched APIC routing to physical flat.  
[    0.088817] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1  
[    0.128593] CPU0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @ 2.70GHz stepping 07  
vendor.  
[    0.237003] [Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)  
[    0.237187] Intel PMU driver.  
[    0.237306] ... version:                3  
[    0.237424] ... bit width:              48  
[    0.237542] ... generic registers:      4  
[    0.237659] ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff  
[    0.237780] ... max period:             000000007fffffff  
[    0.237899] ... fixed-purpose events:   3  
[    0.238016] ... event mask:             000000070000000f  
[    0.239112] NMI watchdog enabled, takes one hw-pmu counter.  
[    0.239343] Booting Node   0, Processors  #1  
[    0.239451] smpboot cpu 1: start_ip = 98000  
[    0.272317] NMI watchdog enabled, takes one hw-pmu counter.
```

**Acá los logs antes y despues de que se apagara:**

```
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   27.955956] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   27.955963] RPC: Registered udp transport module.  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   27.955965] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   27.955967] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   27.969310] FS-Cache: Loaded  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   27.987785] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   28.379645] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   28.390064] iscsi: registered transport (tcp)  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   28.787522] scsi1 : iSCSI Initiator over TCP/IP  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   28.807389]  connection1:0: detected conn error (1020)  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   29.575057] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk        b000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   29.575330] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   29.576147] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 20971520 512-byte logical blocks: (10.7 GB/10.0 GiB)  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   29.576806] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   29.576819] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 77 00 00 08  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   29.577140] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: disabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   29.587075]  sdb: unknown partition table  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   29.588395] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk  
Jun 22 06:09:15 cs05 kernel: [   30.145458] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 1 devices found  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: smartd 6.0 2012-10-10 r3643 [x86_64-linux-3.0.76-0.11-default] (SUSE RPM)  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Copyright (C) 2002-12, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Opened configuration file /etc/smartd.conf  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Drive: DEVICESCAN, implied '-a' Directive on line 26 of file /etc/smartd.conf  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Configuration file /etc/smartd.conf was parsed, found DEVICESCAN, scanning devices  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Device: /dev/sda, opened  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Device: /dev/sda, [HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   8.00], lu id: 0x600508b1001c762f83babda266e088bf, 1.20 TB  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Device: /dev/sda, does not support SMART Self-Test Log.  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Device: /dev/sda, is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Device: /dev/sda, persistence not yet supported for SCSI; ignoring -s option.  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Device: /dev/sda, attribute log not yet supported for SCSI; ignoring -A option.  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Device: /dev/sdb, opened  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Device: /dev/sdb, [LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk        b000], lu id: 0x000000000000004d000eb394a3ecbc370x6000eb394a3ecbc3000000000000004d, 10.7 GB  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Device: /dev/sdb, Bad IEC (SMART) mode page, err=5, skip device  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7847]: Monitoring 0 ATA and 1 SCSI devices  
Jun 22 06:09:16 cs05 smartd[7849]: smartd has fork()ed into background mode. New PID=7849.  '  
Jun 22 14:01:09 cs05 kernel: [28325.328363] No iBFT detected.  
Jun 22 14:01:12 cs05 kernel: [28328.444449] iscsi: registered transport (be2iscsi)  
Jun 22 14:01:12 cs05 kernel: [28328.444453] In beiscsi_module_init, tt=ffffffffa07aa040  
Jun 22 14:04:29 cs05 sm-notify[38981]: Version 1.2.3 starting  
Jun 22 14:04:29 cs05 sm-notify[38981]: Already notifying clients; Exiting!  
Jun 22 18:23:49 cs05 kernel: [44074.430126] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team  
Jun 25 09:08:57 cs05 auditd[6457]: Started dispatcher: /sbin/audispd pid: 6459  
Jun 25 09:08:57 cs05 audispd: priority_boost_parser called with: 4  
Jun 25 09:08:57 cs05 audispd: max_restarts_parser called with: 10  
Jun 25 09:08:57 cs05 audispd: af_unix plugin initialized  
Jun 25 09:08:57 cs05 audispd: audispd initialized with q_depth=80 and 1 active plugins  
Jun 25 09:08:57 cs05 auditd[6457]: Init complete, auditd 1.8 listening for events (startup state disable)  
Jun 25 09:08:57 cs05 haveged: haveged starting up  
Jun 25 09:08:57 cs05 haveged: arch:        x86 vendor:      intel generic:     0 i_cache:     32 d_cache:     32 loop_idx:    30 loop_idxmax: 40 loop_sz:     31836 loop_szmax:  124334 etime:       11872 havege_ndpt  0  
Jun 25 09:08:57 cs05 sm-notify[6517]: Version 1.2.3 starting  
Jun 25 09:08:58 cs05 iscsid: iSCSI logger with pid=6550 started!  
Jun 25 09:08:59 cs05 iscsid: iSCSI daemon with pid=6551 started!  
Jun 25 09:09:00 cs05 iscsid: Connection1:0 to [target: iqn.2003-10.com.lefthandnetworks:txslltsstoragegroup:77:dbm, portal: 192.168.103.50,3260] through [iface: default] is operational now  
Jun 25 09:09:01 cs05 kernel: klogd 1.4.1, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero mira los logs de errores de la bios del servidor. Si es la fuente, ahí puedes encontrar algún dato, por poco que le dé tiempo a escribir.  Por ejemplo, si se calienta porque no le funciona un ventilador, saltará ese error antes de que se apage.

Después cambiaría algo relativo a ACPI en la bios primero por probar. Desactivarlo/activarlo.

Busca actualización para la BIOS por si la hubiera en el fabricante.

Es muy importante instalar en el linux todas las aplicaciones que trae el fabricante, en estas aplicaciones enlaza la bios con los syslogs y se ven mejor los errores.